# How do I read a CSV file?

Tags: ruby, csv, file-io

I have problems reading a CSV file with two columns separated by "\tab".

My code is:

```
require 'csv'
require 'rubygems'

# Globals
INFINITY = 1.0/0

if __FILE__ == $0
  # Locals
  data = []
  fn = ''

  # Argument check
  if ARGV.length == 1
    fn = ARGV[0]
  else
    puts 'Usage: kmeans.rb INPUT-FILE'
    exit
  end

  # Get all data
  CSV.foreach(fn) do |row|
    x = row[0].to_f
    y = row[1].to_f

    p = Point.new(x,y)
    data.push p
  end

  # Determine the number of clusters to find
  puts 'Number of clusters to find:'
  k = STDIN.gets.chomp!.to_i

  # Run algorithm on data
  clusters = kmeans(data, k)

  # Graph output by running gnuplot pipe
  Gnuplot.open do |gp|
    # Start a new plot
    Gnuplot::Plot.new(gp) do |plot|
      plot.title fn

      # Plot each cluster's points
      clusters.each do |cluster|
        # Collect all x and y coords for this cluster
        x = cluster.points.collect {|p| p.x }
        y = cluster.points.collect {|p| p.y }

        # Plot w/o a title (clutters things up)
        plot.data << Gnuplot::DataSet.new([x,y]) do |ds|
          ds.notitle
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The file is:

```
48.2641334571   86.4516903905
0.1140042627    35.8368597414
97.4319168245   92.8009240744
24.4614031388   18.3292584382
36.2367675367   32.8294024271
75.5836860736   68.30729977
38.6577034445   25.7701728584
28.2607136287   64.4493377817
61.5358486771   61.2195232194
```

I'm getting this error:

```
   test.csv:1: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting $end
48.2641334571,86.4516903905
              ^
```

Comment: What is fn mentioned in the first line?

Comment: added the code, it is the file descriptor

Comment: missing an end in the bottom

Comment: Can you build a MWE (without the usage of ARGV...). Of if the ARGV-logic is important: How do you call your script?

Comment: it seems this is the problem i use aptana studio, and the run command  works awkward, now i use the terminal it is fne, than kyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just missing an `end` at the bottom. Your very first `if` is not closed.

CSV are "Comma-Separated Values". Yours are using tabs. This is not a big problem, because the CSV class can handle it, you just need to specify that your separator is a tab:

```
CSV.foreach(fn, { :col_sep => "\t" })
```

Be sure to double-check your file that it is using tabs, not spaces which are not the same.

I'm still confused about the error message, is this everything you received?

Comment: Can you update your question with the updated source & error message. This could help us help you.

Comment: Tab-separated files are called "TSV". They're similar to CSV but it helps to use the right acronym.